# Simple authentication in a alert box for website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, server

I want to have a simple authentication for a website, just for testing purpose. On opening the site for ex: www.example.com the browser should ask user to enter a username and password to navigate to index.html.

How can I do this in JavaScript, I don't mind hard coidng the user name and password. I do not want any database connection. Its a simple 3 page static site deployed in a server. Index.html loads on opening the site.

Comment: You'll need to store the user names and password on the server somewhere (database, static file, etc.) because anyone can view your source code and see what your JavaScript is testing the input against.  Also, you wouldn't redirect to index.html. index.html would be the page that does the verification and then it would redirect to some other page or make an AJAX call to show new data.

Answer (score 0):

Store the valid user name and password in local javascript variables.  On the click event of your login button, compare the input values to your local variables.  As long as this is for testing, it will work.